# I can not run my app in the iPad 5.1, so i need to downgrade it to 5.0 or lower iOS version

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am starting to develop apps with Phonegap, and my app runs in Xcode's simulation mode without problems. But when I try to run it in my iPad I receive this message:

"Xcode cannot run using the selected device.

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

But when I go to Xcode > Window > Organizer the iPad is available in my devices, but there is also the message:

"The version of iOS on “Tool iPad” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on Tool iPad
5.1.1 (9B206)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2"

So I went to Apple developer site with my AppID and did not find any link to an older iOS version. I found this website (http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/) and downloaded iOS 4.3, 4.3_5 and 5.0 for iPad, but when i try to restore the device on iTunes the software extraction starts and the I receive the message:

"The iPad can not be restored. This device isn't eligible for the requested build."

What else can I do? I am using Xcode 4.2 and Phonegap 1.7 and I can't atualize them for work issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update Xcode. You should be using Xcode 4.4.1 to develop on the latest version os iOS. Apple generally releases a new version of Xcode alongside iOS and OS X launches. For example, you will need Xcode 4.5 or later (currently in beta) to develop for iOS 6.

Apple expects you to update to the latest releases of all software when they come out. Bring this to your IT dept. Not only does it require Lion, in the near future, Xcode will require Mountain Lion. There really is nothing else you can do but pressure your IT department to update your machine to 10.8.

The other issue is that Apple stops signing the ipsw(s) for old versions of iOS, thus forcing you to updated. Even if they did, Apple also requires that you build apps against the current release of iOS through Xcode.

Comment: Yeah, but Xcode's requires OS X 10.7.4 or later, and my OS X is 10.6.8. As I said in the question, I can't update my OS X for company issues. And if I can't update the OS X, I can't update Xcode and Phonegap.